# about typeScript array, How can this error be solved

Tags: arrays, typescript

Why is it wrong? help me. What should I do. look img

```
@Prop(Array) menu!: object

created() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        bus.$emit('user', this.menu[0].childs)
    })
}

mounted() {

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please copy the code example into the question instead of attaching the image. You always can show the line generating error with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> You cant access the property `childs` if you have defined the type as
>   `object`. So, you can either define the specific type, or you can use
>   the following.

```
@Prop(Array) menu!: { [index : string] : any}
```